# C++ OpenCV 2.4.0 findContours crashing with Kinect Depth Stream

Tags: opencv, kinect

Running into a problem with opencv 2.4.0 findContours function constantly crashing.  Unfortunately, it's been very difficult for me to pinpoint the issue.  Hoping someone has run into a similar problem.

I'm capturing the depth stream from a Kinect sensor using the Microsoft K4W SDK 1.5, copying that to an OpenCV Mat, then converting it to an 8UC1 image via cvtColor and threshold.  I run a countNonZero just to be sure the image isn't blank before passing it to findContours.  But even the simplest findcountours implementation crashes.

Here's my basic code:

```
rawdepth = Mat(Size(640,480),CV_8UC4);
thresh = Mat::zeros(640,480,CV_8UC1);

// storage for contours 
vector<vector<Point>> contours;

cvtColor(rawdepth,thresh,CV_RGB2GRAY);
threshold(thresh,thresh,0,255,THRESH_BINARY);

if(countNonZero(thresh) > 100 ) {
    // This crashes
    findContours(thresh,contours,RETR_EXTERNAL,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);           
}
```

I did verify that the actual Mat being passed to findcontours is a single-channel image and that it is not blank (ie, there are some 500+ points).  But I'm wondering if this is a heap or thread related problem since I've heard findcontours can actually modify the  input Mat?

At this point I'm going to try and use OpenCV 2.4.1 which was just released, though I don't see any fixed bugs that would point to fixing this problem.

Any ideas are much appreciated...

Comment: Have you traced the crash back to `findContours()` ?

Comment: Yep.  In fact, I can run other functions like Canny on the same image at that point and it works fine.  I also verified the 'thresh' Mat being passed to findContours is a single-channel image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a compiler flag which was limiting the program's stack usage to 10MB (10,000,000 bytes).  Unfortunately this wasn't enough for the Kinect video I was capturing.  After removing the compiler flag, the findContours will now compile and work properly!

I'm using VC++ 2010 and the compiler flags were under Project Properties->Linker->System.  The two fields were: **"Stack Reserve Size"** and **"Stack Commit Size"**

After clearing them and recompiling, the project works beautifully!

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible problems here.

First, the raw depth stream from the Kinect is 16 bit (3 LSB are player index, remaining 13bits are depth in mm) so if you are copying that data into an 8bit image you are only getting half of it and it's gobbledegook.

Secondly OpenCV is compiled differently for debug and release configurations. If you are compiling using a Debug profile you need to use the debug libraries (version#d). So to use cv::findContours you need opencv_imgproc240.[lib/dll] and opencv_core240.[lib/dll]. Neither cv::namedWindow / cv::imshow (which are very handy for debugging) or cv::findContours will work properly if you are using the wrong configuration.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to remark that I had the same problem regarding the crash of the findContours() method, as mentioned in the second answer, the problem was that I was using the non-debug version of opencv_imgproc240.dll and opencv_core240.dll in Debug mode, changing to the XXd.dll solved the problem.

Comment: This should probably be a comment to the existing answer rather than an answer in itself.